# How do I map through this set of objects within array of objects in objects

Tags: javascript

I want the value of `cooked`

```
 var kvArray = [
 {key: 1, value: [{items: 10, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 20}}, {items: 20, price: {raw: 20, cooked: 60}}, {items: 30, price: {raw: 30, cooked: 90}}, {items: 40, price: {raw: 50, cooked: 70}}, {items: 50, price: {raw: 50, cooked: 90}}]}, 
 {key: 2, value: [{items: 40, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 20}}, {items: 30, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 70}}, {items: 20, price: {raw: 20, cooked: 20}}, {items: 10, price: {raw: 20, cooked: 20}}, {items: 60, price: {raw: 60, cooked: 20}}]}, 
 {key: 3, value: [{items: 70, price: {raw: 60, cooked: 20}}, {items: 60, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 70}}, {items: 50, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 60}}, {items: 30, price: {raw: 30, cooked: 20}}, {items: 20, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 80}}]}
 ];


 kvArray.map((kvA , index) =>{
   console.log(kvA.value)
 } )
```

Comment: There are a bunch of `cooked`s. Do you want an array of them for each object, or just to `console.log` em all?

Comment: Not Array but each of them.

Comment: Then don't use `map`, use `forEach`, `.map` is when you need to create a new array.

Comment: you want to console.log each of them? you'll need to iterate on `kvA.value` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another `map()`:

```js
var kvArray = [
 {key: 1, value: [{items: 10, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 20}}, {items: 20, price: {raw: 20, cooked: 60}}, {items: 30, price: {raw: 30, cooked: 90}}, {items: 40, price: {raw: 50, cooked: 70}}, {items: 50, price: {raw: 50, cooked: 90}}]}, 
 {key: 2, value: [{items: 40, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 20}}, {items: 30, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 70}}, {items: 20, price: {raw: 20, cooked: 20}}, {items: 10, price: {raw: 20, cooked: 20}}, {items: 60, price: {raw: 60, cooked: 20}}]}, 
 {key: 3, value: [{items: 70, price: {raw: 60, cooked: 20}}, {items: 60, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 70}}, {items: 50, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 60}}, {items: 30, price: {raw: 30, cooked: 20}}, {items: 20, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 80}}]}
];


var cookedArr = kvArray.map((kvA, index) =>{
 return kvA.value.map(p => p.price.cooked)
});
console.log(cookedArr);
```

**OR:** If you do not need to return anything use `forEach()`:

```js
var kvArray = [
 {key: 1, value: [{items: 10, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 20}}, {items: 20, price: {raw: 20, cooked: 60}}, {items: 30, price: {raw: 30, cooked: 90}}, {items: 40, price: {raw: 50, cooked: 70}}, {items: 50, price: {raw: 50, cooked: 90}}]}, 
 {key: 2, value: [{items: 40, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 20}}, {items: 30, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 70}}, {items: 20, price: {raw: 20, cooked: 20}}, {items: 10, price: {raw: 20, cooked: 20}}, {items: 60, price: {raw: 60, cooked: 20}}]}, 
 {key: 3, value: [{items: 70, price: {raw: 60, cooked: 20}}, {items: 60, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 70}}, {items: 50, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 60}}, {items: 30, price: {raw: 30, cooked: 20}}, {items: 20, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 80}}]}
];


kvArray.forEach((kvA, index) =>{
 kvA.value.forEach( (p, i) => console.log(p.price.cooked));
});
```

Comment: ok map within map. I modified it like this: `kvArray.map((kvA , index) =>{
  kvA.value.map(p => 
    console.log(p.price.cooked)
  )
});`

Comment: @Deke -- You're using arrow function body without any return statement. Either remove the surrounding `{}` or place a `return` before `kvA.value.map ...`.

Comment: @Deke, `map()` should have `return`. If you do not need to return simply use `forEach()`. Please see the second code snippet of the answer.

Comment: Awesomes! map within map is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I will do reduce and then map which will return all cooked value on flat array.

```js
var kvArray = [
 {key: 1, value: [{items: 10, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 20}}, {items: 20, price: {raw: 20, cooked: 60}}, {items: 30, price: {raw: 30, cooked: 90}}, {items: 40, price: {raw: 50, cooked: 70}}, {items: 50, price: {raw: 50, cooked: 90}}]}, 
 {key: 2, value: [{items: 40, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 20}}, {items: 30, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 70}}, {items: 20, price: {raw: 20, cooked: 20}}, {items: 10, price: {raw: 20, cooked: 20}}, {items: 60, price: {raw: 60, cooked: 20}}]}, 
 {key: 3, value: [{items: 70, price: {raw: 60, cooked: 20}}, {items: 60, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 70}}, {items: 50, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 60}}, {items: 30, price: {raw: 30, cooked: 20}}, {items: 20, price: {raw: 10, cooked: 80}}]}
 ];
console.log(
  kvArray.reduce(
    (arr, elem) => arr.concat(elem.value), []
  ).map(a=>a.price.cooked)
)
```